# How to sort items coming from text file in java

Tags: list, arraylist

Actually I'm working on a class to read a text file that contains the following elements:

```
Ringer-ID-0: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-0: {2344343r4efdwdd2w2sdwq}
Ringer-ID-0: volume =100;
Ringer-ID-0: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-1: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-1: {4r3444ewdwdaedw3re3d34d3}
Ringer-ID-1: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-1: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-2: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-2: {23edecrrvt5y66h6hyyhy66}
Ringer-ID-2: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-2: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-3: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-3: {3444444t56756y7h7h6ef}
Ringer-ID-3: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-3: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-4: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-4: {r4rfrf54g65g65g6h7uj7}
Ringer-ID-4: volume = 50;
Ringer-ID-4: speaker = on;
```

what I need to do with these elements is to rearrange them in order to have all HDAUDIO devices with its values in the top of my list and USB devices in the bottom like this:

```
Ringer-ID-0: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-0: {4r3444ewdwdaedw3re3d34d3}
Ringer-ID-0: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-0: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-1: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-1: {23edecrrvt5y66h6hyyhy66}
Ringer-ID-1: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-1: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-2: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-2: {3444444t56756y7h7h6ef}
Ringer-ID-2: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-2: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-3: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-3: {2344343r4efdwdd2w2sdwq}
Ringer-ID-3: volume =100;
Ringer-ID-3: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-4: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-4: {r4rfrf54g65g65g6h7uj7}
Ringer-ID-4: volume = 50;
Ringer-ID-4: speaker = on;
```

I thought first store them in an Array List but I don't know how would be the better way to achieve this, please give a hand, thanks in advance guys

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class RearrangeItems {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\items.txt")));
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                list.add(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            String[] records = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[] { "" });
            for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(records[i]);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the comparator interface useful to look into...

Using this you may sort classes extending comparable using whatever method callback you wish using a class which extends comparator.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

- create a Ringer class with the appropriate fields
- parse the input file and create a list of Ringer objects
- sort the list
- iterate through the list and output a representation of the ringer objects

Here's some working code to demonstrate the idea ...

Ringer class:

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    class Ringer implements Comparable<Ringer> {
        private static final String TYPE_USB = "USB";
        private static final String TYPE_HDAUDIO = "HDAUDIO";
        private static final String RINGER_NUMBER = "Ringer-ID-";

        private String deviceType;
        private String deviceName;
        private String id;
        private String volumeLevel;
        private String speakerState;

        public static Ringer parseAndCreate(String deviceLine, String idLine,
                String volumeLine, String speakerLine) {
            if (deviceLine == null || idLine == null || volumeLine == null
                    || speakerLine == null) {
                return null;
            }

            Ringer r = new Ringer();
            String ringerNumber = null;

            { // device
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + RINGER_NUMBER
                        + "(\\d?):\\s?(.*)\\\\(.*)$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(deviceLine);
                if (!matcher.find()) {
                    return null;
                }
                ringerNumber = matcher.group(1);
                r.deviceType = matcher.group(2);
                r.deviceName = matcher.group(3);
            }

            { // id
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + RINGER_NUMBER
                        + "(\\d):\\s?\\{(.*)\\}$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(idLine);
                if (!matcher.find() || !ringerNumber.equals(matcher.group(1))) {
                    return null;
                }

                r.id = matcher.group(2);
            }

            { // volume
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + RINGER_NUMBER
                        + "(\\d):\\s?volume\\s?=\\s?(.*);$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(volumeLine);
                if (!matcher.find() || !ringerNumber.equals(matcher.group(1))) {
                    return null;
                }

                r.volumeLevel = matcher.group(2);
            }

            { // speaker
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + RINGER_NUMBER
                        + "(\\d):\\s?speaker\\s?=\\s?(.*);$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(speakerLine);
                if (!matcher.find() || !ringerNumber.equals(matcher.group(1))) {
                    return null;
                }

                r.speakerState = matcher.group(2);
            }

            return r;
        }

        public String getFormated(int ringerNumber, String lineSeperator) {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.append(String.format("%s%d: %s\\%s%s", RINGER_NUMBER, ringerNumber,
                    deviceType, deviceName, lineSeperator));
            s.append(String.format("%s%d: {%s}%s", RINGER_NUMBER, ringerNumber, id,
                    lineSeperator));
            s.append(String.format("%s%d: volume = %s%s", RINGER_NUMBER,
                    ringerNumber, volumeLevel, lineSeperator));
            s.append(String.format("%s%d: speaker = %s", RINGER_NUMBER,
                    ringerNumber, speakerState));

            return s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Ringer other) {
            if (this.deviceType.equals(TYPE_HDAUDIO)
                    && other.deviceType.equals(TYPE_USB)) {
                return -1;
            } else if (this.deviceType.equals(TYPE_USB)
                    && other.deviceType.equals(TYPE_HDAUDIO)) {
                return +1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Ringer [deviceType=" + deviceType + ", deviceName="
                    + deviceName + ", id=" + id + ", volumeLevel=" + volumeLevel
                    + ", speakerState=" + speakerState + "]";
        }
    }
```

Application code:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;

    public class RearrangeItems {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                ArrayList<Ringer> ringers = new ArrayList<Ringer>();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                        "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\items.txt")));
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        String deviceLine = reader.readLine();
                        String idLine = reader.readLine();
                        String volumeLine = reader.readLine();
                        String speakerLine = reader.readLine();

                        Ringer ringer = Ringer.parseAndCreate(deviceLine, idLine,
                                volumeLine, speakerLine);
                        if (ringer == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        ringers.add(ringer);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    reader.close();
                }

                Collections.sort(ringers);

                for (int i = 0; i < ringers.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(ringers.get(i).getFormated(i, "\n"));
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```